# Change all font color

Tags: color, fonts, gimp, text

I have a file saved as `.xcf` (gimp native file format) with many text boxes.

*How can I change all the text to a specific color?*

Right now, all of my text is green (`#00FF00`), but I want it to be blue (`#0000FF`).

Double-clicking each text layer and selecting all the text then changing color is repetitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have all the fonts used in these layers:

- get ofn-recolor-text-layers from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/)
- Install as instructed at the bottom of the page
- `Image>Change color of visible text layers...`

If you are missing fonts, the above script cannot be used because to change the layer color Gimp redraws it and therefore needs the font. Furthermore it won't change the color of characters that have been assigned a specific color using the on-canvas dialog, it only changes the general layer color. A work-around where the text layers themselves are not changed:

- Make non-visible all non-text layers (you can mass-control the visible status of layers by shift-clicking the eye icon of any layer).
- `Layer>New from visible` will produce a layer with all you text on transparent background
- At that point you may want to hide the text layers, and to un-hide the rest.
- Set the alpha-lock on the created layer (checkerboard icon at the top of the Layers list under the blend mode selector).
- Bucket-fill the layer with the required color (no selection necessary, the alpha-lock will keep transparent pixels transparent).